# Action on Google push notifications remove permission

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

How can I delete UPDATE permission from my user after grant using simulator?

My Dialogflow webhook always receives this JSON after the first grant, I need to restart.

```
"user": {
  "lastSeen": "2019-06-03T12:20:24Z",
  "permissions": [
     "UPDATE"
  ]
}
```

Comment: For an unpublished Action, the only way to reset the UPDATE permission is asking the Assistant to "stop sending updates from <action_name>", where <action_name> is a placeholder for the name of the target Action. But it's available only in english language.

Comment: here is my pay load {
  "google": {
    "expectUserResponse": true,
    "systemIntent": {
      "intent": "actions.intent.PERMISSION",
      "data": {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.actions.v2.PermissionValueSpec",
        "permissions": [
          "UPDATE"
        ],
        "updatePermissionValueSpec": {
          "intent": "push_notification_handler"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}  but following command is not working stop sending updates from push_notification_handler

Answer (score 0):

Marco,

Once a user grants permission to receive updates, this is cached on the backend, and you will continue to receive the UPDATE permission in subsequent requests.

There is currently no way to reset the permission grant.

Comment: So I have to use a new Google account every time I need to debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

If you have published your Action you can look up the action in the directory and click on the Reset link. If you haven't, then "publish" an alpha release to get a directory entry (alpha releases don't need to be reviewed) and then Reset from there.